# Only show the future 14 days in datetime selector

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Currently this is helper for getting a datetime selector in a form.

I want to improve it by showing only the next 14 days as options. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

```
  def begins_at_for form
    options = {
      :start_year => Time.now.utc.year,
      :end_year => Time.now.utc.year,
      :discard_year => true,
      :default => 3.days.from_now,
      :use_short_month => true,
      :minute_step => 15,
      :include_seconds => false
    }

    if Time.now.utc.yday > 300
      options.merge!( :end_year => Time.now.utc.year + 1 )
    end
    form.datetime_select(
      :begins_at,
      options
    )
  end
```

Comment: I doubt that it can be done with rails but it definitely can be done with JavaScript

Comment: hmm, i was originally thinking on doing it with js. I figured:

# for the month
$('#appointment_begins_at_2i option:not(.selected)').remove();
# for the day
not sure yet. Any ideas? Thx..

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format you can get current date with JS and delete unnecessary day entries but beware of the dates after 17 because you have to enable two months for them and display appropriate day set for each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery and this datepicker.  You can disable days on the calendar, so you could disable all but the next 14 days to do what you want.
http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

Comment: nice, im going to check it out. Thanks!